# How to get the current logged employee's department in a Generic Inquiry in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

For the Vendor Documents page, I need to be able to see the current user's department AP documents so I need to filter them out like so. Since Acumatica has @me function, I thought there was more available but it seems to only branch out to datetimes.

Since the special functions aren't that well documented (as least in my appreciation), I thought it was a possibility to use one but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use the `Contact` table to get the Contact record corresponding to the current user (`@me` parameter holds the ContactID of the current user)
and then from there get the EPEmployee records corresponding to that contact using the UserID reference.
[image]

..
[image]

..
[image]

Comment: I might have misexplained the question, so sorry, not my first language. While you're correct, I was looking for a way to use the current user's department as a perpetual filter in the Inquiry, so that every employee can only see de documents created by their own department. It's imperative that the filter is not a selectable parameter in the UI.

Comment: @GeorgeArce this really comes to the way you define an AP document created by that department. Is the department a workgroup on the AP Document? How is it stored there? Or you are looking for documents created by employees in the same department?

Comment: It seems they don't assign workgroups, so it's going to be the latter: the documents created by employees in the same department

Comment: just my 5c if you create a UDF that is true if the user is the department and only shows true fields on the GI you should be able to achieve this. The setting of the UDF to be true will then be done in a custom Attribute

Comment: @JvD this can be achieved by joining the same table twice with aliases once to get the department of the current employee and the second time to get the employees with that department, then simply join all that to the AP Bills on created by field